# Black bars above and below on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I found a bug in Xcode 9 autolayout. My `UIView` with `UITableView` for iPhone 5s (568px height) get resized to iPhone 4 (480 px height). I don't understand why and how I can fix this bug?

[image]
[image]

As you can see, `self.height` for `UIView` is 416px without statusBar and NavigationBar (416+64 = 480px)
[image]

Inside the storyboard in the simulator for iPhone 5s iOS11, `UITableView` has height of 568px. 
Why my application for iPhone 5s is shown as it was on iPhone 4.

Comment: Never assume you've found a bug. You might have, but it's unlikely. Assume that _you_ are making a mistake. (Hint: you are.)

Comment: Take matt's advice very seriously. The standard method for debugging code is: 1. You realise that _you_ made a mistake. There are no mysterious gremlins out to get you. 2. You find what mistake you made. If you omit step 1, you will never find any bugs in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the black bars above and below the view? This isn't an issue of how views are laid out. It's a more fundamental problem. See where the status bar (with the carrier and battery indicators) is. This status bar is not part of your view hierarchy, but it's not in the right place either. Bottom line, the entire window has been shrunk, not just the views in your app.

This is usually because of a lack of appropriate launch images (and is why we use launch storyboard nowadays). Either supply the missing launch images or shift to a launch storyboard.

Comment: I never encountered a similar problem, but everything fixed.